# Does the Unplugged hindrance limit what Augments you can buy?

Tags: savage-worlds, interface-zero

If I've got a character with the Unplugged hindrance (no TAP, no direct brain to machine interface), can I buy any augments at all?

Based on the description some augments seem software based and some seem purely physical. I couldn't find anything online or in the rule book that mentioned requirements to buy augments other than Strain and Cash.

My question is about the Interface Zero 2.0 setting and rules as written for the Savage Worlds system.

Comment: Also, Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: @Mołot Yes, this is Interface Zero 2.0 using the Savage World Rule set. I saw that 3.0 is coming out soon, but my group is currently rolling with 2.0.

Comment: @Someone_Evil You are partly right. The Interface Zero setting is based on the core Savage Worlds system, but it adds unique rules, and those are the rules I'm asking about. Sorry that wasn't clear in my original question.

Comment: No worries, I was simply going by out tag description (visible on hover; you can get a longer one if you click on it). A few things; no need to signal your edits, simply make it the best version of the question. I've edited it down to only have the relevant information. Also, it wasn't a mod who edited, simply another user. If you have any questions ask us here, or join us in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat) (where usually someone who can help with things).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Yes, it does.

All cyberware is designed to interface with a TAP. Being Unplugged means you can't do that. Unless or until you remove the Unplugged Hindrance, cybernetics of all types are unavailable to your character.

FYI: The 3.0 update is reported to introduce several genetic and chemical augments that can be used without a TAP. Until that material is finalized, this cannot be confirmed.